# Update GUI During Synchronous AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, google-app-engine, jquery

I'm using Google Appengine to run a webapp and I've run into a bit of a problem. I need to generate a pretty big CSV file and send it to the client. Since there is a 60 second timeout maximum and there is no filesystem to write to, I decided to use SJAX (synchronous AJAX I guess) to get the data from the server in chunks, conctenate them, and then send it back to the server where the server sends it back to the client as a CSV file. Very annoying.

Anyways, this takes a very long time so I thought I would use a progress bar that checks how many chunks have been received against how many there are total. The problem is, since I'm using SJAX, the solitary js thread is getting blocked. `setTimeout()` gets blocked as well. Anyone know of any way to get around this (the GUI part, I'm trying to figure a better way to handle the file download separately)?

EDIT: While I appreciate Shay pointing me in the right direction to resolving my problem, I am still curious as to whether there is a way to I guess emulate multi-threading during an SJAX call.

Comment: hmm.. can't you do the requests asynchronously isntead? It sounds like it would just be a matter of rewriting some conse in continuation passing style.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer the part about the CSV generation, since its the root cause of your trouble.

You can generate data using task queue and save it to the blobstore or the Google Cloud Storage. Tasks queue has 10 minutes processing timeout which hopefully should be enough time to generate the data.

You pattern should be: calling a method to start generating the data, using pull to check if the data is ready (or with channels using comet) and downloading it if ready.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I would be doing something like that. The project is due in 1 hour and I first got it a couple of hours ago, so I didn't want to start messing with things I'm not as familiar with. But I will look into that now :)